# How to use Anaconda 3 and 2, on linux ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: python-3.x, anaconda, ubuntu-16.04, python-2.x

Good morning, I wonder if there is a way to use python version 3 and 2 of anaconda, without having to create a "mv_env" of any version? I say this, because ...
I noticed that some fellow install version 3 or 2 on the computer (windows or linux) and make a "mv_env" of the other version, with specific packages. I currently need ipython version 2, but I can not even run the terminal.

PS: When I installed anaconda 3, it exported the path in the .bashrc script. (Because the goal is python 3)

Comment: Its not clear exactly what your issue is.

Comment: I  would like to use anaconda2 and anaconda3, in linux. But I can not, because the only one I can call the terminal is anaconda3, even though both are installed in the system.